# Can someone explain this recursive Java method that reverses a string?

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring, charat

so I'm a junior in college trying to understand recursion. I understand the general concept but not how it's properly implemented. I found this extremely simple code and just can't seem to grasp how the last line (recursion) works. Any help and explanation would be awesome, thanks! (also finals coming up soon and boy am I nervous)

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
    if (s.isEmpty())
        return s;
    return reverse(s.substring(1)) + s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Take a piece of paper, use the input string `abc`, and then write out what happens with all of the recursive calls.  This is really the best exercise you can do here to learn.

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen advised , I think following the flow of one run will help you. Take a string (`abcdefg` or anything non symetric), and run that code with an additional `System.out.println(s);` before the return: you should then understand how it gets manipulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion process removing one by one char using substring , as substring take a beginning index which in 1 in you case so if our string is "ABC" then "ABC".substring(1) then substring will return "BC"
So in your case reverse is processing with substring
lets take our input is "abcd" for reverse methos

then process will like with reverse  method as a recursion

```
bcd -> 1st reverse will call with this value
cd -> then reverse will call with cd
d -> then reverse will call with d
"" -> then reverse will call with "" as its blank string so reverse will terminate
```

once reverse method reach isEmpty statement the s.charAt(0) will start which will add at then end of return output from reverse method so it modified output like

```
d
dc
dcb
dcba
```

so whole process will like:

```
input to reverse method :bcd
input to reverse method :cd
input to reverse method :d
input to reverse method : "" empty string
result received from reverse method  
After modified result with return value from reverse method and charAt(0) operation : d
result received from reverse method  d
After modified result with return value from reverse method and charAt(0) operation : dc
result received from reverse method  dc
After modified result with return value from reverse method and charAt(0) operation : dcb
result received from reverse method  dcb
After modified result with return value from reverse method and charAt(0) operation : dcba
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative version of the same algorithm for clarity, which iterates through the characters of the string in *encounter order* and concatenates them into a new string in *reverse order*, swapping the summands:

```java
public static String reverse(String str) {
    String revStr = "";
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        revStr = ch + revStr;
    }
    return revStr;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(reverse("some text string"));
}
```

Output:

```
gnirts txet emos
```